# Why assignment by Logical Operators ( &&= and ||= ) is missing in C/C++?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

1) Why there is no assignment by logical operator like there is assignment by sum and difference?

```
bool a = true;
bool b = false;
a = a || b;
a ||= b; // syntax error!
a |= b;   // OK.
```

2) What is the meaning of applying bitwise operator on boolean variable?
   Is it the same as using logical operator?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. I don't understand what you are saying?

Comment: @haccks he's asking why there are no compound boolean assignment operators  `||=` `&&=`

Comment: Please ask a proper question. Currently, it is unclear whether you are asking "Why there aren't `||=`, `&&=` etc" or "What's the meaning of applying bitwise operator on boolean variable"

Comment: @CoolGuy Done. Actually now I'm asking two questions .

Comment: For the No 2 question someone should see this post (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice/134136#134136). This link, you reference below, deserves to be here. It will be helpful for new-comers. Directly below the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's true that `&&=` and `||=` are "missing" from C.  I think one reason is that logical AND and OR in C perform short-circuiting, which would be a little strange in the abbreviated form.  But don't use the bitwise assignment operators in their place.  Instead, just write:

```
a = a && b;
c = c || d;
```

The bitwise operators will work if you have canonical true/false values (1 and 0).  But if applied to non-canonical values, such as 5 and 2, you will get different results (5 && 2 is 1, but 5 & 2 is 0).

Comment: Please can you explain what 'short-circuiting' is?

Comment: Is bool type in C always canonical?

Comment: Short-circuiting for `&&` and `||` means that the second operand is only evaluated if it is needed to determine the result.  For example, if you have `0 && x`, then `x` is not evaluated because you already know the answer is `0`.  Similarly, if you have `1 || y`, then `y` is not evaluated because you already know the answer is `1`.  This is significant if the second operand is slow to evaluate (e.g., a function call), or has side effects.

Comment: As to whether bool types in C are always canonical, originally there was no bool type in C.  Later versions of C introduced a bool type, and in C99 stronger support was introduced, but since bool variables are at least 1 byte in size, it is always possible to "force" non-canonical values into them through unions or pointer casting.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Why do you think that it is strange to perform short-circuiting on logical operators in the abbreviated form? Isn't it only a syntax?

Comment: Yes, that's true.  But I think some people would find it unintuitive to have an assignment operator that sometimes ignores its right-hand-side.

Comment: I did some research and it is not only a syntax difference. Assignment by operator correspond to a clearly different machine instruction and addressing mode. Read more [HERE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134118/why-are-shortcuts-like-x-y-considered-good-practice/134136#134136). But I still didn't find a good answer why &&= and ||= are "missing" from C. Knowing the information above, is it now more clear to you why are they missing or irrelevant?

Comment: You are confusing the original motivation for some of these operators (mainly `++` and `--`, which worked naturally for some of the PDP-11 addressing modes) with language semantics.  The C language is independent of specific machine architectures, and modern code optimization techniques make such architecture matching less relevant.  The operators are a convenience today.  It's possible that the "missing" assignment operators may be introduced in a future ANSI C specification, but in the meantime I suspect my answer is probably the best justification for their absence you're likely to find.

Answer (score 2):

`a |= b` means the same as `a = (a | b)`, except that the address of a is evaluated only once. Then you look up the rules for promotion, and for assignment to bool.

Comment: Can you use bitwise operators on booleans?